# Project Management self-evaluation #2: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love our site and Stack Exchange loves our site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find five questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Update:** ***Let's target October 5th as the deadline for this self-eval. Please speak up in the comments below and let your voice be heard!**

Comment: thanks for the great work you do on the site!

Comment: Just FYI, these questions are randomly selected by Stack Exchange using an automated tool. No human selected them.

Answer (score 2):

[How should a project manager assess probationary employees?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/how-should-a-project-manager-assess-probationary-employees)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Interesting question and the quality of the answers is good.

Comment: @Zsolt, I thought this was a little broad, but our community generally does a great job making the answers really awesome, which has a nice side effect of making the questions look a little better. :)  The answers really make this shine.

Answer (score 2):

[What Should a Project Manager Do If Development is Not Completed On Time?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/what-should-a-project-manager-do-if-development-is-not-completed-on-time)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question started out really poor, but through editing and chat we made it shine. I also thought it was good because it highlights some really common misconceptions about the role of a project manager. All answers give solutions and are great, well-thought out, and support the same general ideas. Unfortunately, I can't vote on these since I posted them, but I wanted to get the ball rolling with a comment.

Comment: I agree with @jmort253 - the answers are solid.  I'm skeptical of questions that ask "should" - that's a danger word because what you *should* do generally depends on what you want to optimize. That said, I think the edits to the question resolved that ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

[Agile/Scrum- Tracking external dependency stories](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/agile-scrum-tracking-external-dependency-stories)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This was a great scrum problem. I think similar questions have been asked, which suggests managing inter-related Scrum projects is a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Should I provide my boss and team with documentation about the Scrum process?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/should-i-provide-my-boss-and-team-with-documentation-about-the-scrum-process)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A real life issue with some good advices.

Comment: I'm going to pick a nit again. "Should" is a dangerous word that invites subjective and particular answers rather than objective answers that are generally useful. I believe  questions that ask "What are the consequences of..." are more useful than "should I...."

Answer (score 1):

[What is the difference between Project and Product Management?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/what-is-the-difference-between-project-and-product-management)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This could almost be a question in our meta since there is a Product Management proposal, but understanding the difference between the two is great information for someone new to the world of PM.